# What's the difference between var User = require('models/users') and var User = mongoose.model('User')?

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've read the docs and I understand that I'm not passing an instance of the schema and checked around stackoverflow for duplicates and I did not find an adequate example explaining the differences, use cases and pros and cons for both.

I've been using both these methods almost interchangeably to access a model in a controller file and so I'm wondering what is the difference under the hood between both and what is generally "best practice". It seems more convenient to use `mongoose.model()` when you are in a heavily nested file structure but i noticed it errors out when there is no data stored in the collection. Here is an example using both methods that works fine as far as I can tell.

```
var Slideshow =  require('../models/mongoose/Slideshow');
var Events    = mongoose.model('Events');
Slideshow.find(function (err, slides) {
      Events.find(function (err, events) {
          res.render('demo', {
            slideshow : slides,
            events : events
          });
      });
});
```

If I understand the first correctly, it's just using require to get the user.js mongoose model which defines the schema eventually runs `var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);` where as the second is directly calling mongoose and asking for the model. But aside from that is there any performance differences or use case differences? Is there anything I missed?